# iPad UIPopOverController - is it possible to have transparent background?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

Does anyone know if it possible to have a transparent background for a UIPopOverController on the iPad?

I'd like to put a semi-transparent view inside the popover (hence the desire for the popover itself to have a transparent background).

I *think* it can't be done ... but I'd love to know if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting the transparency of the view in the popover won't work, but I've never tried it and it might.

Anyways, another cool way would be to take a UIImage rendering of the main UIView inside the popover controller.

Once you have this image, you can follow this process, assuming that you also know where the popover is positioned (its CGRect) relative to the view controller that opened it.

1. Hide popover.
2. Show rendered UIImage in a transparent UIImageView at the same position. (You can add a little border yourself so that it looks like the popover too.)
3. Reshow the popover.

The effect would be that the UIPopoverController "faded".

I know its a hard way to do it if the first solution also works, but this might be cool project to take on.

Answer (score -1):

Why not add a View whose alpha is setted to 0.5 before showing popover view

then use

```
presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

method of popover passing the created view's reference.

Comment: Because that doesn't give the desired result.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to have UIPopOverController to have semi-transparent background. Check the following example.

```
[[[myPopOverController contentViewController] view] setAlpha:0.25f];
```

Comment: This will be applied to whole popover not to the background.

Answer (score -3):

Usually popover control wil be transparent,we cant change the popover control to semi-transparent view

Comment: The popover is totally opaque, not transparent.